# Remove empty lines and space with Perl

Tags: perl

How do I remove empty lines and space from a string?

I did a search, but none of the solutions were able to fix my problem. When I print the string, I don't see any special character like \n \t \r. Here is my string:

```
$string= "Current configuration : 17448 bytes

                              |  Current configuration : 17331 bytes


 ";
```

I did the following:

```
$string =~ s/ ++/ /gs;
```

But the output came out like this:

```
Current configuration : 17448 bytes
 | Current configuration : 17331 bytes
```

And I want it to show like this:

```
Current configuration : 17448 bytes | Current configuration : 17331 bytes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $string= "Current configuration : 17448 bytes

                              |  Current configuration : 17331 bytes


 ";

$string =~ s/\s+/ /gs;

print "$string\n"
```

Prints:

```
Current configuration : 17448 bytes | Current configuration : 17331 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $string =~ s/\s+/ /gs;
```

Worked for me