# Ignore empty lines in a CSV file using Perl

Tags: perl, csv

I have to read a CSV file, `abc.csv`, select a few fields from them and form a new CSV file, `def.csv`.

Below is my code. I am trying to ignore empty lines from `abc.csv`.

```
genNewCsv();

sub genNewCsv {
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
    my $aCsv = "abc.csv"
    my $mCsv = "def.csv";
    my $fh = FileHandle->new( $aCsv, "r" );
    my $nf = FileHandle->new( $mCsv, "w" );

    $csv->print( $nf, [ "id", "flops""ub" ] );
    while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {

        my $id = $row->[0];

        my $flops = $row->[2];
        next if ( $id =~ /^\s+$/ );    #Ignore empty lines

        my $ub = "TRUE";
        $csv->print( $nf, [ $id, $flops, $ub ] );
    }
    $nf->close();
    $fh->close();
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Use of uninitialized value $flops in pattern match (m//)

How do I ignore the empty lines in the CSV file?

I have used Stack Overflow question *[Remove empty lines and space with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382199/remove-empty-lines-and-space-with-perl)*, but it didn't help.

Comment: fyi, you appear to be missing a comma between "flops" and "ub"

Comment: Move the 'next if ...' one line up, because you Cañons access elements if the line is .

Comment: Adding to @Gabs00, you have more `syntax` errors: `my $aCsv = "abc.csv"` is missing a `;`. Copy-Paste mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the entire row if any fields are empty:

```
unless(defined($id) && defined($flop) && defined($ub)){
    next;
}
```

You tested if $id was empty, but not $flops, which is why you got the error.

You should also be able to do

```
unless($id && $flop && $ub){
   next;
}
```

There, an empty string would evaluate to false.

Edit: Now that I think about it, what do you mean by ignore lines that aren't there?

You can also do this

```
my $id = $row[0] || 'No Val' #Where no value is anything you want to signify it was empty
```

This will show a default value for the the variable, if the first value evaluated to false.

Answer (score 0):

Run this on your file first to get non-empty lines

```
sub removeblanks {
  my @lines = (); 
  while(@_) {
        push @lines, $_ unless( $_ =~ /^\s*$/ ); #add any other conditions here
  }
  return \@lines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to skip empty lines:

```
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)){
    next unless grep $_, @$row;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils%E2%80%8E%20List%3a%3aMoreUtils) to check if any of the fields are defined:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
while(my $row = ...) {
    next unless any { defined } @{ $row };
    ...
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to use `any { $_ eq '' }`